# Django using the wrong Timezone for the data imported from MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, bootstrap-4, timezone, django-timezone

I use Django 3 + Bootstrap 4 + MySQL 5.7 on a Laragon server, all on Windows 10.

My setting in Django : `TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'`

My setting in MySQL : `TIME_ZONE = SYSTEM` (My system is configured with 'Europe/Paris')

When I use a `timezone.now()` in Django, or a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in MySQL, I have no problem, the right time is displayed.
But my data imported from MySQL are displayed wrongly: with a +2 hours error.
For what I have read on the subject, the cause can be the absence of data in MySQL `time_zone` table, on the server.
What's your point of view ? Am I on the good track ?
I don't want to make a mistake, so I prefer to have a confirmation first.

And do you think it's good to keep the setting so in MySQL. Shouldn't I prefer
`TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'` instead of `TIME_ZONE = SYSTEM` ?

Answer (score 0):

The date data kept in database is always in Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) and django changes it based on the "TIME_ZONE" choice. So when you recieve time data directly from database it is displayed as GMT. If you have to convert it you need to use tz.

```
from dateutil import tz

to_zone = tz.tzlocal()
datefromdatabase.astimezone(to_zone).date()
```

Bon courage!

Comment: First, I want to tank you for your response. 
Second, I followed your suggestion, and found another way when my IDE proposed me a `template_local_timezone` auto-completion. 
After following the track, and reading the documentation, I found a simple and clean option, and I think it's better for me because I'm dealing with objects, not just a datetime.
And I want to use the possibility of Django first. So I will give my solution just below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution whit the **Template tags** in the Django doc : [Time zones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#localtime)

```
{% load tz %}

{% localtime on %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}

{% localtime off %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}
```

For me I just had to use `{% localtime off %}`
Simple as that.